How to patch/update SharePoint list using Formulas PowerApps
How to patch or update SharePoint list by using Formulas in PowerApps
Scenario: Need to add logs upon each button click in the Form. Rewriting same code for each button will be not be a good solution.
 Patch(
'Service Request',
LookUp(
    'Service Request',
    ID=varSRRID
        ),
        {   
            Status: {Value:varTaskStatus},
            User: DataCardValue36.Selected

        }
    );

Trying to utilize above code in UDF Reusable code in Formulas section but getting errors:


What is the error message?

The same syntax does not work in the App - Formula Section.
